# Source for Rav Simcha of P'shischa insight

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-vayeishev

[Many](https://jewishlink.news/features/16300-a-lesson-from-the-checkout-counter) [articles](http://www.hatanakh.com/node/36341) quote a beautiful insight from [Rav Simcha Bunim of P'shischa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcha_Bunim_of_Peshischa) on the posuk ([Bereishis 37:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.37.14?lang=bi&aliyot=0))

> וַיֹּאמֶר לוֹ לֶךְ־נָא רְאֵה אֶת־שְׁלוֹם אַחֶיךָ וְאֶת־שְׁלוֹם הַצֹּאן
> וַהֲשִׁבֵנִי דָּבָר וַיִּשְׁלָחֵהוּ מֵעֵמֶק חֶבְרוֹן וַיָּבֹא
> שְׁכֶמָה׃ - And he said to him, “Go and see how your brothers are and
> how the flocks are faring, and bring me back word.” So he sent him
> from the valley of Hebron, and he reached Shechem.

saying that Yaakov sent Yosef to look for his brothers’ “wholesome" qualities in order for them to have peace with one another. Where can the source of this original insight found? (Honestly, where are any of Rav Simcha Bunim's insights found other than others quoting him?)

Comment: Similar idea in the Chasam Sofer:  דע"י וקרא זה אל זה , קרא בלשון חבה יתירה , עי"ז נעשה שמקבלין דין מן דין , שע"י קריאת השם יקבלו שפע שלהם זה מזה ויאמרו קדוש . Where *shem* = the true, i.e. good, essence

Comment: As far as your bracketed question. L'fi Wikipedia: "During his life, Simcha Bunim wrote no works of his own, but many of his teachings were transmitted orally and published, much later on after his death....Kol Simcha (קול שמחה) – Collection of his oral commentaries on Torah and Talmud. Ramataim Zofim (רמתיים צופים) – oral teachings from Hasidic masters, with him mentioned several times. Simchat Yisrael (שמחת ישראל) – recalls oral commentaries of Simcha Bunim. Midrash Simcha I and Midrash Simcha II (מדרש שמחה) – oral Midrashim given by Simcha Bunim.

Comment: @Dov See also Yakar Mipaz

Answer (score 1):

Bechasdei Hashem Yisborach, I found the source for it in the sefer [Kol Simcha](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10191&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=) of Reb Simcha Bunim himself, it's the third piece in parshas Vayeshev:

> וזה פירוש לך נאה ראה את שלום אחיך שתראה שלמותם ולא חסרונם

It  is written with more clarity in the [Tiferes Shlomo](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9749&st=&pgnum=73&hilite=) of Reb Shlomo Hakohen Rabinowicz of Radomsk in parshas Vayeshev:

> לר נא ראה את שלום אחיך ואת שלום הצאן והשיבני דבר. הנ"ל לרמז בזה עד כמה האדם צריך
> לשמור את עצמו לבל ישים עוול ודבה על חבירו רק יסתכל במעלת חבירו ויעלים עינו מחסרונו
> ...
> וזה הרמז ג"כ כאן שאמר יעקב אבינו ליוסף לך נא ראה את שלום אחיך. פי' השלימות והטוב אשר באחיך תראה ולא תביט בחסרונם. ואת שלום הצ"אן רמז ליחוד הוי' אדנ"י בגימ' צ"א. נו"ן רמז לנ' שערי בינה. והשיבני דבר. לשון תשובה. תחזור בתשובה על אשר פגמת שהבאת דבתם רעה. אך טוב תראה בבנ"י תמיד